# Which number is the car parked on?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Which number is the Land Rover parked on?

[image: puzzle[1]]

Answer (score 5):

My answer is

> $59$
>
>  The sequence advances by the next natural square
>
>  Sequence:
>  $5$ $9$ $18$ $34$ $59$ $95$
>
>  Differences:
>  $4$ $9$ $16$ $25$ $36$
>
>  And the *next* term will be $144$ which is $95 + 49$

Answer (score 2):

> The parking spots fit the sequence [A153058](https://oeis.org/A153058).
>
>  $a(0)=4; \hspace{1em} a(n)=n^2+a(n-1)$
>
>  i.e. Starting from the number 4, add the square of the parking space's index to the previous parking space's number.
>
>  $a(1) = 5$
>  $a(2) = 9$
>  $a(3) = 18$
>  $a(4) = 34$
>  $a(5) = 59$
>  $a(6) = 95$
>
>  The $n^{\text{th}}$ parking space (for $n \geq 0$) can be found using the solved recurrence:
>
>  $\begin{gather*}a(n) = 4 + \frac{n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n)}{6}\end{gather*}$
>
>  Therefore, the missing number, on the fifth parking space, is $59$.
>
>
>  (This is the same answer as [@WeatherVane](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/98313/65935)'s.)